# on keypress jquery function, backspace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeypress

I implemented a function that add white space like so automatically :

```
+33 6 XX XX XX XX
```

or

```
06 XX XX XX XX
```

Here is the script :

```
$('#num').keypress(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    //remove whitespaces to calculate the length of the string
    $val = $this.val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    //if it's the case '+33 6 XX XX XX XX
    if ($val.toLowerCase().indexOf("+") >= 0 | $val == "")
    {
     if($val.length == 3){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }else if($val.length == 4){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }else if ($val.length >= 5 && ($val.length)%2 == 0){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }
    }else{
         if (($val.length)%2 == 0){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }
    }

});
```

It works perfectly on chrome but on firefox i can't backspace the input.. Any ideas ?

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate :

https://jsfiddle.net/jd1mwp3p/

Comment: Note that from a UX perspective, it doesn't really work in Chrome either.  One example - type a number, realise you've transposed two digits.  Select them and try to overtype them the right way round - wierdness ensues.

Comment: oh right, didn't try this... That's weird am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to think about here.

The first one is that different browsers handle keypress,keyup, keydown, differently. In particular when it comes to non printable chars, such as backspace, some browsers fire the keypress event and some don't. Firefox does, and Chrome doesn't.

Now if you look at your code, you don't take in consideration backspace. Indeed what you do is adding a space if there is no + sign and the value is even:

```
else{
         if (($val.length)%2 == 0){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }
    }
```

and you again add a space if the value is 3 4 or 5 chars long when there is a + or the value is empty:

```
if ($val.toLowerCase().indexOf("+") >= 0 | $val == "")
    {
     if($val.length == 3){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }else if($val.length == 4){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }else if ($val.length >= 5 && ($val.length)%2 == 0){
            $this.val($this.val() + " ");
        }
    }
```

So. Chrome ignores your keypressed event and just deletes the chars, firefox calls your event and you do not handle backspace.

Comment: Thank you but, it's not an answer ! keypresss function doesn't allow to handle non printable keys like backspace...

Comment: the keycode for backspace should be 8 and 46 for delete. As I mentioned not all browsers call keypress on backspace, so I would probably use keyup

Comment: You can even leave it like this and put an if statement to return if the keycode is 8. browsers that don't fire the event will work anyways, and browsers that do will return

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud, did you find this helpful? did you find another solution? If you solve please accept an answer or let us know what solution you found

Comment: Like you said i handled the backspace with keycode 8. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter non-printable keypress events, in case the browser is firing them.

For instance, for backspace:

```
$('#num').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 8) {
    return true;
  }
  $this = $(this);
  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.keydown` and you do not have to worry about checking whether backspace or not! because it will work with any key pressed.